# Allocating storage to store one item and set its value to something

Tags: c

so I've been tasked with writing a function that allocates storage to store one item and set its value to an input. the function is initializeItem, and the struct is relevant so I've included it.

```
typedef int Info;
typedef struct {
    Info info;
} Item;
typedef Item* ItemRef;

ItemRef initializeItem(Info g){
/* allocates storage to store one item and sets it to value g */
    Item item;
    item.info = g;
    printf("g = %d", g);
}
```

I believe I'm supposed to use malloc, but I'm unclear as to how to apply it to this situation. Also, what kind of return should this function have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
ItemRef initializeItem(Info g){
/* allocates storage to store one item and sets it to value g */
    ItemRef ptr = (ItemRef) malloc(sizeof(Item));
    if (!ptr) {
        std::cerr << "error. " << std::endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    ptr->info = g;
    return ptr;
}

int main() {
    ItemRef ptr = initializeItem(25);
    if (!ptr) {
        std::cerr << "error. " << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << ptr->info << std::endl; // 25
        free(ptr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As a sanity check, I ran this on valgrind.

```
==21934== HEAP SUMMARY:
==21934==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21934==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 4 bytes allocated
==21934==
==21934== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is that, in the function `initializeItem`, your variable called `item` is local to the function, so when the function returns that variable will go out of scope and the memory where it lives can later be overwritten, etc.

From your code it looks like you want `initializeItem` to have a return type of `ItemRef`, which is a pointer to `Item`.  Note that in your code your `initializeItem` does not actually return anything.

The reason you should use `malloc` is that you do not lose ownership of memory given to you by `malloc` when you leave the scope of the function from which you call `malloc`.  It seems like a `malloc` tutorial may be helpful for you.

Anyway you probably want something like this:

```
ItemRef initializeItem(Info g) {
    ItemRef item_ref = (ItemRef)malloc(sizeof(Item));
    item_ref->info = g;
    return item_ref;
}
```